# Performance implications of having 10.000 items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to know the performance implications of having 10.000 items in a SharePoint list, and having a view that displays 100 items per page, and then to page through these 10.000 items each time I click on "next" to go to the next page of the view.

Will SharePoint query all of the 10.000 items regardless of the item limit set on the view, or will it query 100 items only each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single SharePoint list or library can contain millions of items, but a single view can only deal with a much smaller set, a specified by the list view threshold. Playing with that threshold is not recommended, as explained in the paragraph Alvin quoted. Here's a longer abstract from [Manage lists and libraries with many items](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-11ecc804-2284-4978-8273-4842471fafb7#__toc264017709)

> Why is 5,000 such a magic number?
>
> To minimize database contention, SQL Server often uses row-level
>   locking as a strategy to ensure accurate updates without adversely
>   impacting other users who are accessing other rows. However, if a read
>   or write database operation, such as a query, causes more than 5,000
>   rows to be locked at once, then it's more efficient for SQL Server to
>   temporarily escalate the lock to the entire table until the database
>   operation is completed. Note that the actual number is not always
>   5,000, and can vary depending on your site, the amount of activity in
>   the database, and your site's configuration. When this lock escalation
>   occurs, it prevents other users from accessing the table. If this
>   happens too often, then users will experience a degradation of system
>   performance. Therefore, thresholds and limits are essential to help
>   minimize the impact of resource-intensive database operations and
>   balance the needs of all users.

Even if you set paging in your view, SQL still needs to know the total set of items in the scope of your query, and in fetching that it will go through row locking or table locking. The list view threshold applies *before* view paging. Note that grouping is also bad as it must be calculated on the entire set (regardless of pages).

The performance impact of meddling with the threshold can be signigicant. See for example the first graph in [this blog post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx)

A couple of other things to note about the list view threshold: a lot of operations could be blocked on "containers" (folders) with a number of children exceeding the threshold. Such as:

- Adding / removing columns
- Adding / removing indexes
- Deleting folders with more items in it than the threshold

(See "Blocked operations when list exceeds the list view threshold" in the last linked articled for a more complete list)

Dealing with large lists is an art. Even after you read through all the TechNet documents, you'll still find behaviours not explained by any of them. Best advice : Plan ahead and avoid containers (folders) with more than 5k items.

Comment: I actually had a bet on in 2010 that vNext (which would become SP2013) would physically limit the number of items in a list down to 5,000, because the number of people switching off LV thresholds. Instead they now recommend using search to large query lists :D

Answer (score 0):

If you set the page item limit to 100, SharePoint only queries for those 100.

10,000 items in the list isn't that much really. SharePoint performs rather well even if you have several hundred thousand of items in the list.

What you don't want is unique item permissions on all those items, as when you query for items it'll internally return the ACL for each uniquely secured item, and that can add significant size the returned data, slowing down queries and views.

Comment: thank you,  based on (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx), the list List view threshold is 5000, are you sure this will not effect the performance.

Comment: Yeah, the list view threshold is 5000 items but if you're bringing back 100 at a time then that won't affect you. Another thing to note is Lookup, Managed Metadata and People/Group columns - those can slow things down, but pure text/number/date columns (the primitive types) can have surprisingly good performance.

Comment: James that is not correct. You cannot have a view that handles more than the list view threshold, regardless of the paging. The query is indeed handling all 10k items at some point. Alvin's answer is actually more true.

Comment: You're actually right, been a while since I dealt with this - originally we were told to page items in code, so we did. Then idiots still didn't do it so they brought in LV thresholds - these are implemented at the database and applied at the web app level. This effectively wiped out perfectly fine handling of large datasets with default settings. Now, we have search which allows stupidly fast querying of 10s of millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against having 10.000 items in a single row. I have changed the item threshold in the past and seen significant performance issues.

"When users perform operations against a database, SQL Server locks rows to prevent conflicts from concurrent operations. Once operations start to affect more than 5,000 items the entire table gets locked because it is more efficient than locking the individual rows. SharePoint stores all list items for an entire content database in a single table"

I would recommend reading the following article for a more detailed explanation 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/quentin/archive/2014/07/15/the-list-view-threshold-_2800_stop_2100_-don_1920_t-change-it_21002900_.aspx

Comment: Consider rewriting your sentence about "10,000 items in a single row" - as in the context of SharePoint this makes no sense. Users have no idea how many rows in SQL a SharePoint item consumes, nor can they control it.